# Destroy action test cases rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, rspec3

m new to rails and rspec
**I have a controller with destroy action**

```
  before_action :authorize_user, only: %i[edit update destroy]

  def destroy
    @question.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to questions_url, notice: 'Question was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

**I have a private method**

```
  def authorize_user
    redirect_to root_path if @question.user_id != current_user.id
  end
```

**This is the rspec test case I have written**

```
  describe "DELETE /destroy" do
    context 'When user has signed in ' do
      let!(:user) { create(:user) }
      before do
        sign_in(user)
        
      end
      context 'User who created the question can destroy' do
        it "destroys the requested question" do
        
          expect {
            question = create(:question, user: user)
            # question.user = user
            # delete :destroy
            delete question_url(question)
          }.to change(Question, :count).by(-1)
        end
      end    
    end
  end
```

**I am getting error like this**

```
expected `Question.count` to have changed by -1, but was changed by 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create your question in the expect block, because then you get a total of 0 count changes (`0` before you create, `+1` for the create, `-1` for your destroy action). If you move that line outside the `expect` block, I suspect your test will pass.

```
  question = create(:question, user: user)
  expect { delete question_url(question) }.to change(Question, :count).by(-1)
```